# Outside scope this key word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why I'm getting undefined with the code below. I tried to declare a variable under the say method var _this = this and then console.log out _this.name but it did not work.

```
let dog = {
  name: 'doggo',
  sayName() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
let sayName = dog.sayName
sayName()
```

Comment: window.name="test"; sayName()//test

Comment: You probably want to be using a class: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoGLQq

Comment: @james because of??? This has nothing todo with inheritance

Comment: Under the assumption that the poster wants multiple dogs with different names

Answer (score 3):

```
window.name="test";
sayName();//test
```

Executes the function in *window context* so this is window. You may want to keep the dog context either through passing it:

```
sayName.call(dog);//doggo
```

Or through keeping a bound function:

```
let sayName = dog.sayName.bind(dog);
sayName();//doggo
```